# hive single node setup

Tags: hadoop, hive, admin

The question is regarding hive and pig setup in my single node running hadoop .As per one good tutorial I setup the hadoop I tried some sample example map reduce program too.Then I downloaded PIG and Hive from apache and I did the configuration .Those things also working fine.But when I compared my thing with HortonWorks or cloudera distribution I found that I don't have an option for Browser access to Hive/Pig.Hadoop cluster I can access using http://localhost:50070/  .So could anyone help me for achieving the same 
Note : I am using Hadoop 2.6 
       Hive 0.9
       PIG  0.12
I am using elementary OS Freya.All the processes are running fine for Hadoop and Hive

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you are loking for a [Hue](http://gethue.com/).
Read more at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue_%28Hadoop%29)

This is optional addon for Hadoop eco system.